# Is asking for the name or link of an anime's song on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I took a look on [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and found the following to be *off-topic*:

> Asking for the **lyrics of a piece of music**, from a particular series or media

And I'm not sure by what accounts as *general* in this:

> Tropes, terminology and other general anime and manga related information.

My question is simple: Can a user ask for the identification of a song for a particular anime playing at a specific time in an episode?

Comment: The answer to your question is simple: yes, you can ask for the identification of a soundtrack for a particular anime.